# Imprimir um vetor novo mudando a ordem dos elementos do vetor original

Tags: python, array, funções

Como faço para mudar a ordem dos elementos de um vetor `v1` imprimindo um novo vetor `v2` com essas mudanças?

Tem como fazer escrevendo uma função `def`?

Exemplo:

```
v1 = [2,51,68,10]
v2 = [10,2,51,68]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo vetor carrega: Índice e Valor

v1 = [2,51,68,10]

```
print(v[0]) #2
print(v[1]) #51
print(v[2]) #68
print(v[3]) #10
```

Como aparentemente você quer mudar a posição sem obedecer alguma lógica (i.e de maior pra menor) vai precisar mudar manualmente o índice na hora de criar o segundo vetor:

```
v1 = [2,51,68,10]
print(v1) #[2, 51, 68, 10]

v2=[v1[1],v1[0],v1[3],v1[2]] #Trocas feitas manualmente
print(v2) #[51, 2, 10, 68]
```

Podem haver soluções mais inteligentes, mas não consegui enxergar algum padrão na troca de índices ou dos valores em si.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o sample do pacote random:

```
from random import sample
v1 = [2,51,68,10]

def embaralha(x):
    return sample(v1, len(v1))

v2 = embaralha(v1)
print(v2)
```

Uma das possíveis saídas:

```
[51, 68, 10, 2]
```